# Is there a way to record the specific user of a command for future use without a database?

Tags: discord.py

So I'm working on a discord bot using discord.py and I'm trying to create a bot for the moderation team in a server, the bot will swap the 'Moderator' role with a 'Leave of absence' role for when they're not active, however the code I have come up with has a slight loopholing problem that I just can't figure out, the code for the commands is this

...

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator')
async def sl(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    loa = ctx.guild.get_role(848032714715561985)
    mod = ctx.guild.get_role(848032880709074944)
    await member.add_roles(loa)
    await member.remove_roles(mod)
    await ctx.send("I have filed your Leave, take care, we look forward to your return!")


@client.command()
async def sr(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    mod = ctx.guild.get_role(848032880709074944)
    loa = ctx.guild.get_role(848032714715561985)
    await member.add_roles(mod)
    await member.remove_roles(loa)
    await ctx.send("Welcome back!")
```

...

as you can see anyone could use the second command to just give themselves a moderator role, I can't set the second command to be moderator only use as the moderator will no longer have said role from using the first command, I'm racking my brain to think of a work around i.e. logging the command users id to a whitelist and having only those whitelisted id's be able to use the second command, I've done many googlesearches for this but have come back with no results, any suggestions would be appreciated, please forgive that this question is a bit lengthy and I'm still very new to coding in general so any help at all, even if you don't fully understand what I'm blabbering on about would be very appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the loa role in the command (ex):

```py
mod = None
for role in ctx.author.roles:
   if role.id == 848032714715561985: mod = True
if mod:
    #your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

So from your question, I'm guessing that you would like to code basically a "storage" file and make sure the person on the leave of absence was previously a moderator.

What you could do is create a csv file, for example `records.csv` (in the same folder as your main .py file of course), and every time someone calls the `sl` command, the program will record the user that used it.

```
import csv

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Moderator')
async def sl(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    loa = ctx.guild.get_role(848032714715561985)
    mod = ctx.guild.get_role(848032880709074944)
    await member.add_roles(loa)
    await member.remove_roles(mod)
    file = open("records.csv", "w")
    file.writelines(str(ctx.author.id))
    file.close()
    await ctx.send("I have filed your Leave, take care, we look forward to your return!")


@client.command()
async def sr(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.author
    mod = ctx.guild.get_role(848032880709074944)
    loa = ctx.guild.get_role(848032714715561985)
    found = False
    with open('records.csv', 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == str(ctx.author.id):     
                 found = True
                 break
    if found = False:
        await member.add_roles(mod)
        await member.remove_roles(loa)
        await ctx.send("Welcome back!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("We do not have history of you having a moderator role.")
```

Are you running the program through an online environment like Repl.it? If so, this may not be the best way to approach this problem since people would have access to your this `records.csv` file (which you may not care about but just in case). If you are running the program through your desktop file directories, then there should be no privacy concerns.

Comment: I'm running it off of a local rpi4 at the moment, but that suggestions sounds like exactly what I'm after, thank you so much!

Comment: Will the code suggestion you gave, store and check multiple id's? VSCode is also saying that

Comment: if found = false:

is throwing an incorrect syntax error at me

sorry for multiple comments, I'm a slow typer and the edit timer is ass